# How do I format UITextField text in real time, while it's being edited?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I change value of `UITextField` text while typing?

In other word:

when I type 1 it should show 1

when I type 10 it should show 10

when I type 100 it should show 100
but

when I type 1000 it should show 1,000

Can you give any idea?

Comment: If i write 1, in uitextfield 1
If i write 10, in uitextfield 10
If i write 1000, in uitextfield 1,000 etc.
while typing decimal change result by that format

Comment: you wanna insert " , " while you type 1000.am i right?

Comment: Use `UITextField Delegate` methods..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add a "textFieldDidChange" notification method to the text field control.

```
[textField addTarget:self
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)theTextField
{
    NSLog(@"text changed: %@", theTextField.text);

    NSString *textFieldText = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[textFieldText integerValue]]];
    textField.text=formattedOutput;            
}
```

Comment: it is working good, but it is just work for number has 4 lenth.

Comment: if i write 1000, this works good,
if i write 10000, this clear numbers after ,

Comment: in ios 7 & xcode 5 : if i write 1000, this works good, if i write 10000, this clear numbers after

Comment: @KK. your code works fine but there is one problem if user enter dot it just removes it.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
    if([string length]==0)
    {
        [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
        [formatter setGroupingSize:4];
        [formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
        [formatter setSecondaryGroupingSize:3];
        NSString *num = textField.text ;
        num = [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
        NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]]];
        textField.text = str;
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
        [formatter setGroupingSize:2];
        [formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
        [formatter setSecondaryGroupingSize:3];
        NSString *num = textField.text ;
        if(![num isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            num = [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
            NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]]];
            textField.text = str;
            NSLog(@"add:%@",str);
        }
        return YES;
    }
}
```

**P.S.** This code is in `ARC`, take care of memory management in non arc environment.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift:**

Be sure to select the **text field input as number pad**, then:

In your viewDidLoad:

```
yourTextField(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Then, in that same view controller:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == yourTextField {

            // Some locales use different punctuations.
            var textFormatted = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
            textFormatted = textFormatted?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")

            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            if let text = textFormatted, let textAsInt = Int(text) {
                textField.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: textAsInt))
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

add action:

```
self.amountTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

in action:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == amountTextField {
        
        var textFormatted = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")
        textFormatted = textFormatted?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        if let text = textFormatted, let intVal = Int(text) {
            textField.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: intVal))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Be sure that `textField.keyboardType = .numberPad`
2. Implement the UITextFieldDelegate method:

   ```
   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

   guard let text = textField.text else {
       return true
   }

   let modifiedText = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

   let formatter = NumberFormatter()
   formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
   formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
   formatter.groupingSeparator = ","

   let modifiedTextWithoutGroupingSeparator = modifiedText.replacingOccurrences(of: formatter.groupingSeparator, with: "")

   if let formattedNumber = formatter.number(from: modifiedTextWithoutGroupingSeparator) {
       textField.text = formatter.string(from: formattedNumber)
   }

   return false
   }
   ```

Answer (score -3):

Try this one.. You can write following line  in `ViewDidLoad` method and give delegate to the textfield.

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and write the following method.

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textfield{
  NSLog(@"here %@",textfield.text);
  if ([textfield.text isEqualToString:@"1000"]) {
    textfield.text=@"1,000";
  }
}
```

Comment: Two things I want to ask.1. If I write 1000 0r 100000 or putting more than 3 zero after 1 still it is showing 1,000 or 1,0000.And second one Is it necessary to add selector in viewDidLoad.What will happen If I have declared the text field as Local variable.

Comment: yes it will be same. i just give it as static to know the idea. Yes we need to add selector. It is necessary. we don't have textFieldDidChange: as a delegate. so we need to add selector.

Comment: sorry u didn't get me.as you wrote add the selector on viewDidLoad not necessary in viewDidLoad.If you declare as local then put selector their otherwise anywhere as instance var.know problem static answer if user accidentally put 3 zero and remove one still there is a comma.I don't think it is an answer as so many cases are arising from the above code.